# Creating a rectangle which contains circular buttons which resize based on the size of the rectangle

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a multi part question. (I'm using React)

1) I'm trying to create a HTML/CSS component which looks like a Mac application (that is, a rectangle with rounded corners and a taskbar with 3 circular buttons on top)

I currently have:

```
<div className='bash'>
  <div className='taskbar'>
     <div className='close-button button'></div>
     <div className='minimise-button button'></div>
     <div className='maximise-button button'></div>
   </div>
   <div className='main-window'></div>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.bash {
    height: 21%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bash>.taskbar {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bash>.taskbar>.button {
    background: red;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This creates [image: Failed window]

When I want it to look more like [image: Expected window]

That is, I want the circles to be relative to the size of the taskbar and next to each other rather than on top of each other. I've tried to use % for the height and width of the buttons but to no avail, so how can I get this to work?

(I've replicated something similar in [codepen](https://codepen.io/sohaib94/pen/wvMojym))

2) I'm fairly new to front end dev work so assumed that I would create the shape using HTML and CSS but have just heard something about SVG. Am I supposed to be using the SVG tag to create this asset? And if so, why is it recommended compared to the way I am doing it? (And if you have any recommendations on learning resources, that would be great :D )

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look to this codepen https://codepen.io/lerouxb/pen/DlJht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using your current code this is how you achieve what you want

```css
.bash {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bash>.taskbar {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* this is new */
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /* this is new */
    padding: 16px; /* this is new */
}

.bash>.taskbar>.button {
    background: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* this is new */
.bash>.taskbar>.button + .button {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

2) I don't know where you heard that but HTML + CSS is the preferred way to go, SVGs are for scalable graphics

Comment: Hi ludwiguer, this is amazing, thanks so much for this and the codepen you provided!
With regards to SVG it may just have been my own misunderstanding from seeing them used on a similar site instead of using css. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it: flexbox layout, div float, grid layout.

```
.bash>.taskbar {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; // Add flexbox
}
```

flexbox guid: [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi Arthur, thanks for responding. I'm going to accept ludwiguer's answer as it answers the question completely but I appreciate your response.